# Using Selected Output of C# Program to other C# Program

Tags: c#, input

I want your help in the matter that I have an C# Code which is for K-Means (Clustering) and I want to use the Output of this code which are 3 Clusters(Say Cluster 1,Cluster 2,Cluster 3)..So I want to select suppose Cluster-1's Output and use it as an Input to my Other C# Program (which is basically MPF)... so please can you provide me the way how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are doing this, but here is an option for you.  Call the first application from within the second using type System.Diagnostics.Process and then use the "RedirectStandardOutput" property to get the information you seek.

more info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx

Comment: thanks I'll make a try and let you inform..actually I am combining 2 Algorithms to produce a Buying-Pattern

Answer (score 0):

One reasonable option is to compile the first program as an API that goes to a static library or a DLL, and compile the second an an EXE that makes reference to the first.

Comment: can you please provide me some details what you wanna say...like some link having such kind of example..thanks for response

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288466%28v=vs.71%29.aspx is one of the many ways...